# Is it ok to run same model multiple times?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

My Question is I ran a keras model for 100 epochs(gave epochs=100) and stopped for some time for cooling purpose of CPU and GPU.
Than I ran 100 epochs again and loss is decreasing from where it has stopped in the previous 100 epochs .
Is it works in all conditions.
Like if there are on 1000 epochs I want to train my model, can I stop after every 100 epochs and wait until my cpu and GPU cools and run the next 100 epochs.
Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work in **all** conditions. For examples if you shuffle the data and perform a validation split like this :

```
fit(x,y,epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

You will use the entire dataset for training which is not what you expect.

**Furthermore**, by doing multiple fit you will erase history information (accuracy, loss, etc at each epoch), given by :

`model.history`

So some callback functions that use this history will not work properly, like EarlyStopping (source code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L733)).

Otherwise, it works as it does not mess around with the keras optimizer as you can see in the source code of keras optimizers ([Adadelta optimizer)](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L353).

**However, I do not recommend to do this.** Because it could cause bugs in future development. A cleaner way to do that would be to create a custom callback function with a delay like this :

```
import time

class DelayCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self,delay_value=10, epoch_to_complete=10):
        self.delay_value = delay_value # in second
        self.epoch_to_complete = epoch_to_complete 


    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if (epoch+1) % self.epoch_to_complete == 0:
            print("cooling down")
            time.sleep(self.delay_value) 
        return


model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1, callbacks=[DelayCallback()])
```